# Incomplete data received across network from C# to Arduino

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, arduino, tcpclient

I am trying to send a word over to an Arduino running as a server, from a WPF C# application. Every now and again the complete work is not sent.

#### C# Code

```
public void send(String message)
{
    TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
    ConState.Content = "Connecting.....";
    try
    {
        tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.0.177", 23);
        ConState.Content = "Connected";

        String str = message;
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);

        stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

        tcpclnt.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ConState.Content = "Not Connected";
        return;
    }
}
```

How it is sent to the method:

```
String mes = "back;";
send(mes);
```

#### Arduino code:

```
if (client.available() > 0) {
    // Read the bytes incoming from the client:
    char thisChar = client.read();

    if (thisChar == ';')
    {
        //Add a space
        Serial.println("");
    }
    else {
        //Print because it's not a space
        Serial.write(thisChar);
    }
}
```

The Arduino is using the chat server example. I am sending "back;" and "forward;" across. The results on the serial monitor:

```
back
forwaback
forward
back
forwaforwar
```

Comment: it's kind of hard to tell what's going on.. does the `Stream` having anything to do with it...? you really should show the full code block..

Comment: The full code block? after that its just catching the exception.

Comment: are you `Freeing the Stream` by the way it looks currently you have `potential memory leak issues

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean `Freeing the Stream`

Comment: It would be useful to see how `forward;` and `back;` gets to the stream exactly.

Comment: Hope that helps. The `send(mes);` is inside a timer set to 1 second

Comment: So a new connection is made for every command?  Yeah, maybe more of arduino code would help.

Comment: Yes a new connection is made each time, I couldnt get it to work to send on a existing stream. The complete code can be seen at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ChatServer I have only removed the last bit

Comment: Have you tried changing `if (client.available() > 0) {` to `while (client.available() > 0) {`?  I honestly don't understand why they read it one character at a time like that.

Comment: That appears to have worked. Thank You.

Comment: How do I accept that as an answer or do I just leave it ? Never asked question on here before.

Comment: You can't accept "comment" as an answer. I guess I'll make it an answer so that it can be accepted and the thing closed.  Maybe.  I'll ask on meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174694/best-way-of-handling-long-debugging-comment-exchanges), and then we'll go from there.  Anyway, glad it is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with this code:

```
if (client.available() > 0) {

  // read the bytes incoming from the client:
  char thisChar = client.read();

  ...
}
```

What it does is:

- Check if we have received data from the client
- **Read a single byte from the client buffer**
- Exit, and go on to do other things

As the OP pointed out, this comes direct from Arduino [chat server example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ChatServer). In that example, this working correctly in `loop()` depends on the `alreadyConnected` flag being set right after a new connection is made: if it isn't, then the buffer is flushed before any data is read.  That's one possible landmine.

---

Nonetheless, there is no reason to change the `if` block to be a `while` loop in the OP's case so, in other words instead of

```
if (client.available() > 0) {
```

have

```
while (client.available() > 0) {
```

The only reason to have an `if` statement there is to make sure that you frequently do other processing in `loop()` if you have clients that send a lot of data: If the reading of client data is done from inside a `while` this loop will not exit until the there is no more data from the client.  Since this doesn't seem to be an issue in the asked-about case, the `if` to `while` change makes sense.